# Use primary key during transaction in entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am creating few models, inserting them with "InsertAsync" and at the end i am saving the changes with entity framework core.

What i would like to do is:

```
MasterDbContext.table1.AddAsync(object1);

var object2 = new table2()
            {
                Action = 1,
                PrimaryRef = object1.primaryKey,
            };

MasterDbContext.table2.AddAsync(object2);
```

But the that value is null, do you know how could i have a second insert with the value?

I mean, if they are executed one by one, entity framework should be able to map the value, if so, anybody knows how? thanks.

*** UPDATE

Basically to make it more simple:

I have a foreach loop where add (without saving) several object in **table1** and **table2**.

In the same loop then i have to log the primary keys of both the tables in **table3** (two different rows)

And then save everything at the end.

how can i take let EF know to take those primaryKeys?

Comment: `But the that value is null,` - which value null? `object1.primaryKey` is null?

Comment: Hi sorry for confusion, after inserted in db.the value on table2 that i tried to take from the primary key of the insert in  table1

Comment: For me, still unclear. What is the problem?

Comment: You have to save changes between for that way to work.

Comment: Still confusing! are you saying that the record on table2 is null after insert while table1 has the record?

Comment: @RyanSchlueter as said, Gabriele, have you called `MasterDbContext.SaveChanges()` after all the query?

Comment: In addition of the SaveChangesAsync, take a look at your async methods, you probably want to await them.

Comment: @gatsby yes! But This would not be an issue as if there is no await then it will be executed synchronously.

Comment: Thanks everybody, i update the question to make it more clear

Comment: What is your reasoning for not wanting to save until the end?  Perhaps you should consider using a transaction, executing save on the individual records, then committing the transaction at the end.  Can post as answer if you think that will work for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a foreign key relation between the two database objects in Entity Framework.

So on your second entity (table2) you must add

```
[ForeignKey("PrimaryRefId")] public table1 PrimaryRef { get; set; }
```

And in your table1, make a reference back :

```
public Collection<table2> SecondaryObjects { get; set; }
```

Now EntiryFramework *knows* the tables are related and you can leverage that relation.

```
var t2 = new Table2 { Name = "Stuff child" };
var t1 = new Table1 { Name = "Stuff",  PrimaryRef = t2 };

MasterDbContext.table1.AddAsync(t1);
```

Comment: This is may be not the issue!

Comment: Sorry this would not work for me, because is not a foreign key, the value can be the primary key of different tables